# jQuery validation issue for allowed characters

Tags: jquery, validation, character

I use jQuery validation in a PHP page. For a specific input field I set the following criteria:

```
accept: "[A-zÀ-ú0-9.,'& -]+"
```

I want to allow alphanumeric characters (both lowercase and uppercase), point, comma, single quote, ampersand, blank space and hyphen.

It seems to work fine, but I noticed that characters `\` (backslash) and `^` (caret) are still accepted.

Is this a jQuery bug? If not, could you please help me to find out what's wrong with the code? Thank you in advance